# Associate toggle with another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, click, toggle

I have a problem combining a toggle function with another function involving a change of the css 'position' attribute.

I have a starting page with a menu at the top and columns of pictures beneath it. 
Some columns are higher than the window and they can be scrolled down together with the menu (both in position: absolute).

When you click on an item from the menu however, the columns hide and another set of pictures appears (triggered by a click+toggle function). This new set is horizontal and this time I need the menu **not to scroll** with it.

So what I'm trying to do is to **change the position of the menu from absolute to fixed, according to the state of the toggle.**

At first I tried including an if/else statement inside my click function but the 'else' part never worked. Now I'm trying to use the callback property of the toggle, but I can't seem to make it work either... The best I can do is get the menu's position switched to fixed, but then it stays that way.

one of the uneffective try-outs:

```
function fixMenu(){
    ('.menu').css('position','fixed')};

function freeMenu(){
    ('.menu').css('position','absolute')};




$("#menu_item").click(function(){

$("#horizontal_set").toggle(1000,fixMenu);
$(".column").toggle(1000,freeMenu);

   });
```

I have no idea whether my problem is in the syntax or if I need a completely different solution. Please enlighten me :-)

Many thanks

PS: I made two little sketches but it appears I'm not allowed to share them :-( I hope my problem remains understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

It checks via an `if-statement` if `horizontal_set` or `column` is visible. and invokes the correct function as a result.

```
function fixMenu(){
    $('.menu').css('position','fixed')};

function freeMenu(){
    $('.menu').css('position','absolute')};




$("#menu_item").click(function(){

    $("#horizontal_set").toggle(1000);
    $(".column").toggle(1000);

    if ( $( "#horizontal_set" ).is( ":visible" ) && $( ".column" ).is( ":hidden" ) )
    {
        fixMenu();
    }
    else
    {
        freeMenu();
    }


});
```

Comment: I didn't know exactly what properties were triggered by the toggle

Comment: @Supernova For future reference, you could use Google (first result): http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/

Comment: thank you, I got drown between the different things I was trying

Answer (score 0):

You forgot jQuery selectors in the function. Try:

```
function fixMenu() {
   $('.menu').css('position','absolute');
}
```

Comment: Haha didn't even notice that while posting my answer.. thanks!

Comment: I didn't even notice in your answer, if I would have, I would have commented :) Happy to be of help :D